# Helm - Launching a group of PVC in same AZ on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy the [gitlab omnibus chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_omnibus.html) to my kubernetes cluster (setup across two AZs) using helm charts. The gitlab-gitlab pod uses 3 PVCs which are backed by EBS and they're generally created in different AZs. What's the idiomatic way in helm to deploy a set of PVCs in the same AWS AZ?

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue recently. There's a workaround for making it work but not correct solution yet.

You need to create a storageclass in a particular zone. This is how it would look like:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
  storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "false"
  labels:
    k8s-addon: storage-aws.addons.k8s.io
  name: gp2-us-east-1a
parameters:
  type: gp2
  zone: us-east-1a
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```

Next step is to setup gitlab deploy in same zone. There are two ways of do that.
You could use `nodeSelector` or `node affinity` which .

Some examples of changes:

NodeSelector example:

```
nodeSelector:
  failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-1a
```

Node Affinity example:

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
          operator: In
          values:
           - us-east-1a
```

This is a bug in dynamic provisioning. The a proposal for the same is present [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/pull/1857) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/storage/volume-topology-scheduling.md)